# I am using google API Oauth2 for google sign-in on my website. How do i get the full name and email id variable from this code into my php code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-api-client

Here is the code from Google's developer website. I am just a beginner at this. I don't know how to get these variable into php so that I can insert them in my database.

```
<script>
   if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
      var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
      console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
      console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: write an ajax call that will post all values to your php file

Comment: @NidhinChandran   I am not familiar with ajax. All i know is php. Can you please post a link to a walkthrough or a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery library you can write something like this. Then all details will be available in the $_POST variable inside data.php . This code will give you the general idea.

```
if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
userData = {
    id: profile.getId(),
    name: profile.getName(),
    givenName: profile.getGivenName(),
    familyName: profile.getFamilyName(),
    imageUrl: profile.getImageUrl(),
    email: profile.getEmail()
};
$.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: userData,
    }).done(function(response) {
         // finish function
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // error function
  });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
    var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
    userData = {
      id: profile.getId(),
      name: profile.getName(),
      givenName: profile.getGivenName(),
      familyName: profile.getFamilyName(),
      imageUrl: profile.getImageUrl(),
      email: profile.getEmail()
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "data.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: userData,
    }).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      console.log('error');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am very very new to this. So please dont mind me asking  A STUPID question. But should i put this code between <script> tags?

Comment: what is a jquery library

Comment: <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script> is this it?

Comment: check jquery.com, i have added a code snippet, check that too.

Comment: i have changed the url from data.php to my page    and also called $_POST['name']     in my php code. didnt work. probably i am doing something wrong

Comment: it shows undefined index whatever i enter inside $_POST['name']    . Here is a part of the code.    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 *had to cut short few lines to fit in comment*
 
    var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
    userData = {
    id: profile.getId(),
    name: profile.getName(),
    email: profile.getEmail()
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "index.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: userData,
 
 <?php
echo $_POST['name'];

?> }
});
</script>

Comment: why did you add `<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>` in javascript code ?

Comment: Sorry i actually echoed it outside the <script> tag.

Comment: `<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>` use this in your php file

Answer (score 0):

The caveat to this approach is that you're only validating the user's credentials client side without validating the token server side. That means someone can fake a name and email address to your server side endpoint and pretend to be authenticated with google.

If your primary purpose is to consume google services, this might be OK. If not, and you want to validate users using Google for your own services server side, you need to validate the oauth server side.  Consider using Google's [beta PHP library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) for this purpose.

One of the issues you may face is that Google has API limits on how often you can validate tokens.